# i am making a All language Translation android app and using searchable spinner to show user language. Now i want to show also country image with lan

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

[This is which I actually want in our app but I am too little bit confuse in implementation. Please guide me. I am doing my project in kotlin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qGwY.png)

[This is which I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyFNO.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your example image, you are trying to create a country picker. For this, you can use this dependency in your code

https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

this dependency makes it very easy to implement the country picker of your project, if you don't want to add any dependency for country picker then you have to add all the country flags in your drawable folder and maintain a list with flag name, country code, and country name.